# Using Bootstrap's popover plugin inside a Javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the popover plugin work inside a Javascript string. So when a user mouse-overs `geolocation` the popover will appear, and disappear when the mouse is taken away.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#directions-panel').text("We can't give you directions to our office as you don't have", <a href="#" rel="popover" data-content="Some content..." data-original-title="Some title..." > geolocation </a> " enabled on your browser. Enable geolocation and try again. The map above will show you where our office is located.");
</script>
```

And invoked using something like this??

```
$("[rel=popover]")
    .popover({
        offset: 10
    })
    .mouseover(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
```

I know it's a bit all over place, but I've searched around and can't find anything similar to what I want to do. I'm sure it can be done, anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

I know have the following in contact page:

```
<div id="directions-panel">
        <div id="directions-error-message" style="visibility:hidden">
          We can't give you directions to our office as you don't have <a href="#" id="geoloc-popover" rel="popover" data-content="Some content..." data-original-title="Some title..." > geolocation </a> enabled on your browser. Enable geolocation and try again. The map above will show you where our office is located.
        </div>
</div>
```

and DIV `directions-error-message` is made visible when the following JS `function failure()` fires:

```
function failure() {
        alert("Your browser does not have geolocation enabled so we can't give you directions to our office. Enable geolocation and try again, or consult the map for our address.");
        $("#directions-error-message").css({
          visibility: 'visible'
        });     
        var destMapOptions = {
          zoom:15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(ourLocation.lat, ourLocation.lng)
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), destMapOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: ourLatLng,
          map: map,
          draggable: false,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          title: "Hello"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
    }


    $(function() {
        $('#directions-error-message').popover({
            selector: '[rel="popover"]', 
            trigger: 'hover'
        });
    })
```

Is there a way to just make 'geolocation' in the `directions-error-message` DIV trigger the popover?

Comment: All you have to do now is change `$('#directions-error-message')` to `$('#geoloc-popover')`. You are setting the popover trigger to the whole div with the ID #directions-error-message instead of just the link.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. I put the trigger inside `failure` but still no difference. I want to select the anchor by ID? Would that not be something like `$('a[id="#geoloc-popover"]')`?

Comment: You do not want the trigger inside the failure function. And the id of any tag can be referenced with just `#theidvalue` so you do not need `a[id="#geoloc-popover"]`. Try removing the selector line from the popover function. Just should be `$(function() { $('#geoloc-popover').popover({trigger:'hover'});})`.

Comment: Actually the best way for you to implement the popover function would be using the code you had originally and just add the `trigger: 'hover'` option. That way is more generic and will apply to any popovers you want to use, where as calling it out by name will only effect the specific link in your example.

Comment: Well I think I finally figured it out. I checked the debugger in chrome and got an Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. My JQuery file was placed at the bottom of the html document (as Bootstrap recommends) so the ready function was being called before JQuery was loaded. I just moved the JQuery file to the header and it's working now, thanks for the help!

Comment: @MattSull87 It would be better practice to move your JavaScript code to the bottom of the page after jQuery loads, rather than move the jQuery to the header.  There is no reason that your code needs to run inline in the body.

Comment: @Jaambageek By using the `selector` option, the popover object is only *delegated* to the element to which it is attached. Rather than *"setting the popover trigger to the whole div"*, it is only setting the trigger on those elements inside the div which match the selector, which in the OP is only a single link. This technique of delegating event listeners is common practice for handling dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like this instead:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">
  We can't give you directions to our office as you don't have", <a href="#" rel="popover" data-content="Some content..." data-original-title="Some title..." > geolocation </a> " enabled on your browser. Enable geolocation and try again. The map above will show you where our office is located.
</div>
```

Then change the visibility of the div with javascript. That way the jQuery setting the title will recognize the link but the user doesn't see it until you want them to.

Comment: Thanks that seems a better solution to what I tried and it works, however I want the popover to toggle on mouseover, like the way @merv is suggesting below.

Comment: The default action for a `popover` is on hover, so I am not sure what you mean. It sounds like from your question you were having issues with it activating the popover because the HTML element didn't exist when the page was drawn. Perhaps I am reading it wrong but can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: @Jaambageek The default option in v2.1 is no longer `hover`, but `click`.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that and revised my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Twitter Bootstrap's Popover plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) does have an option to enable its data-api to trigger toggling popovers.  Enabling it will make all dynamically added elements with the proper markup work without further initialization calls in JavaScript.

The feature is disabled by default mostly because subscribing to all the **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events on a page could pose performance issues (which is the default in TBS < 2.1).  If you can keep the activated area relatively specific, you should be fine performance-wise.

To enable it just for the `#directions-panel` on hover, the syntax would be:

```
$('#directions-panel').popover({selector: '[rel="popover"]', trigger: 'hover'});
```

All subsequent updates to the panel which include popovers will then be active by default.

Comment: I literally only have one thing that I want a popover for so performance shouldn't be an issue, but thanks for pointing it out any way. I only want the anchor tag that holds geolocation (as shown in original question) to trigger the popover. would it be possible to go `$('#directions-error-message a').popover...`?

Comment: That would work if you call it *after* the anchor is added, but the whole point of opting in to the data-api is so that ajaxy things don't require subsequent calls. If you know that you are only going to apply it to an anchor tag, you could use: `$('#directions-panel').popover({selector: 'a[rel="popover"]')`.  The popover object must be attached to something persistent on the page.  The `selector` value is what specifies the elements.  As long as you aren't adding `rel="popover"` on other anchors, then they will be ignored.